# Formatting numbers while printing

Tags: formatting, calculations

Is there a way to format number strings while printing?

Suppose I have the following declaration:

```
\newcommand{\MyNumberA}{40}
\newcommand{\MyNumberB}{60}
```

The following in the text:

```
\the\numexpr(\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB)\relax
```

will produce 2400. I want to print 2,400 or 2,400.00.

Am I asking too much or this can be done? How?

Comment: another relevant package: [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `siunitx` package to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyNumberA}{40}
\newcommand{\MyNumberB}{60}

\num{\the\numexpr(\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB)\relax}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

You can define your own command to handle this too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\num[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{\the\numexpr(#1)\relax}}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyNumberA}{40}
\newcommand{\MyNumberB}{60}

\mynum{\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB}

\end{document}
```

**Regarding comment about non-integer values:**

I would follow @egreg's suggestion and take advantage of the fact that `siunitx` ueses `expl3` internally.  In this following example, I create a separate command to handle floating point values.  I also provided the macro with two arguments.  The first argument is optional to allow you to modify how `siunitx` handles its content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\myeval{m}{\fp_eval:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\num[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{\the\numexpr(#1)\relax}}
\newcommand\myfpnum[2][]{\num[group-separator={,},
                            group-minimum-digits=4,
                            round-integer-to-decimal,
                            round-mode=places,#1]{\myeval{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\def\MyNumberA{40}
\def\MyNumberB{60}

\mynum{\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB}

\def\MyNumberA{40.1349}
\def\MyNumberB{60.9982}

\myfpnum[round-precision=3]{\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine as long as the numbers are integers. If I change use a decimal fraction, it breaks. Any remedy there.

Comment: @deshmukh I've updated my answer.  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 12):

If you also want to print two zeroes after the number use this `siunitx` setup:

```
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4,round-integer-to-decimal,round-mode=places}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyNumberA}{40}
\newcommand{\MyNumberB}{60}

\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4,round-integer-to-decimal,round-mode=places}
\num{\the\numexpr(\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB)\relax}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to change the default number of decimal digits, use the option `round-precision`.

For example, adding to the `\sisetup` the option `round-precision=3` you'll get 3 zeroes after the integer part.

Comment: the additional key `round-precision = ` (default value `2`) can then be used to change the number of digits after decimal mark.

Comment: @jfbu Of course, thanks. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a new command based on `\num`, exploiting the fact that `siunitx` uses `expl3` internally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]{siunitx}
% \usepackage{xparse} % already loaded by siunitx

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\numc}{ O{} m }
 {
  \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n{ #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyNumberA}{40}
\newcommand{\MyNumberB}{60}

\numc{\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB}

\numc[
  group-separator={,},
  group-minimum-digits=4,
  round-integer-to-decimal,
  round-mode=places,
]{\MyNumberA*\MyNumberB}

\end{document}
```

As you see, local options can be specified for `\numc` in the same way as for `\num`.

[image]